# Calling DWR library and JQuery library

Tags: javascript, jquery, dwr

I am new to DWR and I need some clarifications in the subject. I have some code that is using DWR engine and I want to implement JQuery events but if I put this header

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
```

above the script to get DWR ready to work

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="ajax/core/engine.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ajax/core/util.js"></script>
```

JQuery does not work.

And if I put it below, DWR does not work.

Does anyone have some info that can help me to understand this better?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
```

to your application, sometimes there is conflicts between different libraries, this might solve your problem.

Take a look [here](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/) for more information.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Do I need to add something before I add this code to my application?

Comment: The jQuery library... there is a few ways to handle these conflicts, take a look in the mentioned link for more info, but i'm not sure this is your problem at all.

Comment: great! this is what happens..I am using dwr (engine.js /util.js) version 2 and I think there is a compatibility issue with google chrome because everything works in IE and FF but not in chrome.

Comment: So maybe its something of your code that's not compatible with chrome? can you post your code that's not working?

Answer (score 0):

Add `jQuery.noConflict` below `JQuery` libraries, then add `DWR` libraries.

i.e.

```
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery.noConflict();
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="ajax/core/engine.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ajax/core/util.js"></script>
```

Now it should work.